# CiviCRM not creating Wordpress user accounts on member registration

Tags: wordpress, civimember, user-account

We are seeing intermittent behavior with CiviCRM and Wordpress. Sometimes the membership registration page will create a new Wordpress account as expected. Sometimes it doesn't. What would cause this behavior?

The CiviCRM membership registration page has the Wordpress account creation required checked in the profile and primary e-mail is present on the form. Here is the form for reference: https://aslta.org/membership/selection/

WordPress 4.3.1 CiviCRM 4.6.6

Comment: intermittent behaviour is really hard to pin down. any common characteristics?

Comment: are the users definitely entering a username and password on the registration page?

Comment: Yes, the username and password are required -- so they are entering it. What I'm seeing is that once in a while there will be a WordPress registration for a given CiviCRM membership registration. I haven't been able to see any common characteristics among them yet.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for this question - I have had the same issue and I don't have the skills to pin it down. We have a "members only" section of our website and so having up-to-date WP Users is quite important. As a workaround, I go in about once a month and export "current" members from CiviCRM and then import them into WordPress to ensure that there are WP User accounts for each. It's messy but...

I thought it was just a bug with how we've got CiviCRM/WordPress setup (we're amateurs and muddling our way through!).

(Sorry this isn't a comment - I don't have enough cred yet to post them :). But it's an answer, just not a good one!)

Comment: Yeah! Glad to hear that we're not the only ones seeing this. I'll probably start looking into filing a bug with the CiviCRM team.