# New contact created every time I login!

Tags: wordpress

I have no idea where to start looking to fix this issue. Every time I login as admin CiviCRM seems to create a new user contact for me. So there's currently a gazillion contacts for my email address (well, 10,000, which is nearly a gazillion).

I'm running CiviCRM 4.6.8 on WordPress 4.3.1.

Comment: is this the same site with these issues? http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6791/civicrm-not-creating-wordpress-user-accounts-on-member-registration if so it sounds like there is some fairly fundamental issues afoot with your basic set up. i can't point to the cause, but somethings worth checking, when you move around the site are you ever changing from http to https or from www to no-www - if either then suggests your base url in civicrm.settings.php needs checking

Answer (score 2):

I've just had a similar problem with a Joomla installation. It was a problem with the civicrm_uf_match table that (in Joomla) links CMS users to Civi contacts. Somehow the CMS user ID in that table was not the current user ID. Civi created a new contact because it could not match the Civi contact back to the user. I don't know how that matching happens in WordPress but it might be worth a look.

To solve in Joomla, I manually changed the CMS ID in the records in the uf_match table to the correct, current CMS ID.

Comment: I am not sure how the uf_match issue you describe would result in new Contacts being made each time Admin logs in - can you clarify

Comment: I'm not sure either. But the OP said "I have no idea where to start looking to fix this issue".  If the WP issue is similar to the Joomla one I have experienced, the new Civi contact could be created if the admin logs into the front end. She doesn't specify this. Maybe the answer isn't very helpful but it **is** somewhere "to start looking" ...

Answer (score 1):

Since the last update, and since switching from MyISAM to InnoDB databases, the problem has resolved itself. I've a suspicion that it was a MyISAM vs InnoDB issue.