# Something is seriously wrong with CiviCRM - Replicating Contacts

Tags: contacts, duplicate-contacts

Wordpress 4.7.5 & CiviCRM 4.7.19

My contact is replicating in our system, to the point there were 700+ records with just my email and name.  I am not sure what is happening but I have some ideas. Every time I do something on CiviCRM it creates a new contact.  Not sure if this is true, but it does not seem to make new contacts while I am away.

Lastly, when I login with my other admin account, none of these issues exist and my user does not replicate anymore.  When I login to my user account, it replicates again.

Should I not have users that are also members, donors, etc act as administrators?

Comment: It will help folks to help you if you explain what version of CiviCRM you are using with what CMS. And also expand a little more on what you are trying to achieve. I understand your frustration, but I have no clear picture of what goes wrong when. As far as the 'should I not have users that are also members etc.' goes: that depends, do you want all your members to be able to log in to CiviCRM? Remember not each CiviCRM contact will have to be a user in your CMS?

Comment: The dedupe error you're seeing is a known bug. See https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20556.

Comment: I suggest you study the bogus contact records, specifically the contact source on the Summary tab and the info in the Change Log tab, for clues about what  is causing the duplication. Look also to see if those contacts have events, contributions, activities, etc. The more info you provide, the more likely someone will be able to offer a solution.

Comment: @BobS - Thanks, I have removed reference to it as it is unrelated. I also just turned on logging in CiviCRM.  Updating log above.  Thank you for tip.

Comment: I doubt that the error in your log is related to the multiple contacts issue. That looks like someone clicked on a malformed link where the event ID was incorrect, e.g. "&id=33." instead of "&id=33". What info can you glean from the bogus contact records?

Comment: From the record itself I just see 
Action: Insert 
Log Type: Contact 
Date: 2017-05-31 10:45:00 
Altered Contact **** (Me)
Altered By **** (Me)

Comment: Consider what you were doing at 10:45 and see if you can determine exactly what triggers a new contact to be created. Is there a regularity in the creation times, suggesting it is caused by a cron job?

If you have any custom modules/plugins/extensions, try disabling them.

One way to easily monitor new contacts being created is Search | Custom Searches | Date Added to CiviCRM. Enter today for the start date and check it periodically to determine what may be triggering the contact creation.

Comment: I have removed my user as an admin in civicrm and wordpress, resynced users with wordpress and civicrm, and now there are no duplicate contacts. However, now I sometimes get the following error: Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. I have removed my user as an admin in civicrm and wordpress, resynced users with wordpress and civicrm, and now there are no duplicate contacts.

Comment: Nevermind - Its still happening, even with administrator privileges removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the email account associated with a WordPress (or other CMS) account by editing the "UFMatch".  If you're SQL-savvy, the correct table is `civicrm_uf_match`.  If you want to do it through the web browser, and you acknowledge that this is a tricksy maneuver, you can do this:

- Go to **Support menu > Developer > API Explorer**.  "Support" menu might be called "Help" menu, it switched somewhere in 4.6.
- Set "Entity" to "UFMatch", "Action" to "Get".  In "Parameters", Set "CiviCRM Contact ID" to your admin account's name.
- Press "Execute".
- In the "Results" area below the "Execute" button, note the value of "id".  There are two "id" values - you want the one INSIDE the "values" stanza.  See screenshot below.
- Copy/paste the entire results somewhere safe in case something gets messed up!  Better yet, do this on a test copy of the database.

Now that you have the ID of the UFMatch record you want to change, go ahead and enter the new details:

- Keep "Entity" as "UFMatch", change "Action" to "Create".  For "UFMatch ID", put in the ID you just found.
- Press "Add Parameter" twice.
- Set the "CMS ID" to the WordPress user ID of the account you want to link to.  Set the "CMS Unique Identifier" to the email address of the same WordPress account.
- Press "Execute".

[image]

Comment: This is super helpful.  I ended up just changing the email of the record and create a new record for the other user.  Its all good now.  Glad to know if this happens again, we can use the API Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is clear.

Example of issue:  Wordpress admin account is Admin, somehow connected to xyz@otheremail.com contact on CiviCRM.  xyz@otheremail.com wordpress account is also an admin, whenever xyz@otheremail.com logs in as an admin on wordpress and tries to do something, it creates a new xyz@otheremail.com contact.  The Wordpress admin account should be connected to abc@email.com record in civicrm but instead is connected to xyz@otheremail.com record in civicrm and is causing issues.

A solution could be to assign the admin wordpress account to another civicrm record, such as abc@email.com but I do not see a way of doing so.

Other stackexchange questions seem to share this same issue.

[CiviCRM not creating Wordpress user accounts on member registration](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6791/civicrm-not-creating-wordpress-user-accounts-on-member-registration)

[New contact created every time I login!](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6883/new-contact-created-every-time-i-login)